# dropdown was working on localhost, but not on server? possibly .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, drop-down-menu, navbar, dropdown

I've uploaded a static website to server, and after realising the filepath was in the URL (eg, .co.uk/index.html) I've followed instructions on how to use .htaccess to remove. But now my dropdown options in my navbar don't work. No error message.
In localhost, the dropdown appears, but file doesn't exist (I think thats because I removed the file ext),
But on server, the dropdown doesn't even appear, in order to make a selection.

dropdown list:

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Services
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="physio">Physiotherapy</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="massage">Massage</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="pilates">Pilates</a>
              <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="injuries.html">Sports Injuries</a> -->
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="accupuncture">Acupuncture</a>
            </div>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try adding a base tag to head of your html document `<base href="/">` or use an absolute path starting with `/` in your href links. Let me know if this helps

Comment: _“No error message.”_ - where did you _look_ for any? Did you check the browser console - for issues such as 404s for stylesheets or other external resources?

Comment: @starkeen, that didn't work. I've now removed the htaccess file, and realised that my dropdown within the navbar doesn't work with/without the htaccess. :/ but does when i test it in chrome.

Comment: @04FS no errors in browser console.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.